# Enlace roto en CSS con propiedad Background

Tags: css, css3

tengo el siguiente error:

HTML

```
<div id="portada">
    <img class="bg-foto">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.bg-foto {
    width: 66px; height: 60px;
    background: url('../imagenes/css_sprites.png') -140px -130px;
}
```

La imagen se muestra pero dentro de una caja de enlace roto. Es decir se ve la imagen pero también aparece como si estuviera rota.

He comprobado con el inspector la ruta y funciona. Además en otros html´s funciona bien con otras imágenes.

¿A que podría deberse tal error?

Muchas gracias a todos.

Comment: ¿Has probado a borrar la caché?

Comment: Si, no era problema de la caché. He editado la pregunta con mi solución, gracias @FranciscoRomero

Comment: Gracias por la información. Editado y respuesta añadida. @blonfu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gracias a todos por vuestra ayuda. La error reside en que las etiquetas `<img>` fueron creadas para llevar de forma "obligatoria" el atributo `src=''` con la dirección. De no llevarla algunos navegadores pueden interpretarlo como un error al no estar bien formado. La solución ha pasado, para mi caso, en cambiar las etiquetas `<img>` por `<div>`.

Comment: Me parece que `src` no es una subetiqueta sino un atributo de dicha etiqueta `img`

Comment: Cierto, editado gracias @Aprendiz

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que chequear si los puntos y barras ("../" , "../../", etc) antes de comenzar a escribir tu enlace están correctos desde dentro del CSS. Recuerda que, por ejemplo, en JS los enlaces tienen que estar escritos como si estuvieran siendo accedidos desde el html aunque el JS esté dentro de una carpeta de javascript. Estoy 100% seguro que ese es tu problema. Lo más facil es ir probando con lo siguiente: "./", "../../", "../" y cuando te funcione, te fijas cual te ha funcionado y comprendes el por qué.

Comment: No era un problema de rutas, he editado la pregunta con mi solución. Gracias @Cristian